# How can we ensure that the combination of functions `(x) => Context(y)` and `(y) => Context(z)` is correct in Dart during the syntax analysis phase?

Tags: dart, generics, functional-programming

How can we ensure that the combination of functions `(x) => Context(y)` and `(y) => Context(z)` is correct in Dart during the syntax analysis phase?

I'm attempting to develop code that allows the combination of monadic functions, which return values wrapped in a context. I have managed to create a function that exhibits satisfactory behavior:

```dart
O2 Function(T1)
      combine<T1, T2, T3, O1 extends MetaState<T2>, O2 extends MetaState<T3>>(
          O1 Function(T1) f1, O2 Function(T2) f2) {
    extractor(x) => x.extract();
    return (T1 x) => f2(extractor(f1(x)));
```

But for this I need to write something like this:

```dart
var p = combine(
        (int x) => Value<int>(x + 5), 
        (int x) => Value<String>('$x'));

var p2 = combine(p, (int x) => Value<String>('$x')); // error in the IDE
```

And the goal is in the following syntax:

```dart
var p = ImmutablePipeline()
      .bind((int x) => Value<int>(x + 5))
      .bind((int x) => Value<String>('$x'))
      .bind((int x) => Value<String>('$x')); // but not error in the IDE
```

And here's an example of a simple class that performs the task but does not perform the correctness checking during the syntax analysis phase:

```dart
class ImmutablePipeline<T extends MetaState> {
  final Function? pipeline;

  const ImmutablePipeline({Function? initial}) : pipeline = initial;

  T2 extractor<T2>(MetaState<T2> x) => x.extract();

  ImmutablePipeline<T> bind<S>(T Function(S) f) {
    if (pipeline == null) {
      return ImmutablePipeline<T>(initial: f);
    } else {
      T newf(x) => f(extractor(pipeline!(x)));
      return ImmutablePipeline<T>(initial: newf);
    }
  }

  MetaState produce(T s) {
    return pipeline!(s.extract());
  }
}
```

I have tried many variations, but I have not achieved the desired result. Generics in Dart seemed very complex and non-trivial to me in this case. It is also important that the usage of the class is not overly complicated and that the function composition is generic across different contexts. Perhaps someone knows a better way to solve this problem? Or a solution? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what all the classes you use are doing.

If you want to abstract over the monad itself ("generic over different contexts" suggests so), you likely cannot. That would require higher-order generics, which Dart doesn't have.
If you just want to have different instantiations of the same monad, it should be doable.

Simply doing a monadic combine is "easy":

```dart
MetaState<T3> Function(T1) combine<T1, T2, T3>(
  MetaState<T3> Function(T2) second, Metastate<T2> Function(T1) first) => 
     (T1 v1) => second(first(v1).extract());
```

That works, and so does something like:

```dart
abstract class EmptyPipeline<S> {
  ImmutablePipeline<S, T> bind<T>(MetaState<T> Function(S) initial) =>
     ImmutablePipeline<S, T>(initial);
  MetaState<Never> produce(S s) => throw StateError("Empty pipeline");
}

class ImmutablePipeline<S, T> {
  final MetaState<T> Function(S) pipeline;

  const ImmutablePipeline(this.pipeline);

  ImmutablePipeline<S, R> bind<R>(MetaState<R> Function(T) f) =>
     ImmutablePipeline<S, R>((S s) => f(pipeline(s).extract()));

  MetaState<T> produce(MetaState<S> s) => pipeline(s.extract());
}
```

if that is what you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. I understood the limitations of Dart generics and found the problem in my code. I think what you have suggested to me should be more than sufficient for my needs

Answer (score 0):

You should see how https://pub.dev/packages/fpdart does it.  Very clever tricks by introducing meta-generics in the form of HKTs.

And just why are you reinventing fpdart?  Why don't you contribute there?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Regarding the fact that I am reinventing fpdart, that's not entirely accurate. I am creating a different package with a specific scope of application that can be used with fpdart if needed. However, I don't want to introduce dependencies on fpdart as it gives me more freedom and independence for my specific use case. Another motivation is that I am still learning Dart and functional programming concepts, and this mini-project allows me to dive into these areas with practical experience.

Comment: Regarding HKTs, thank you for highlighting that. I need to analyze the code further to understand how HKTs solve the problem with type analysis.

Comment: This link is helpful: https://marcosh.github.io/post/2020/04/15/higher-kinded-types-php-solution.html as in it talks about HKTs using PHP.  I mean, PHP!??!

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. Now I have something to think about and a topic to read in the evenings. Maybe I'll need something like HKTs to achieve higher types in a non-functional lang